# Error for Raising a Web Service using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm doing these days my first steps with Spring Boot. I used this article https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#use-maven to build a simple web service.

This is the code I wrote:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}


package com.example;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHi() {
        return "Hi";
    }

}
```

I run it by "sprint-boot:run".The code compiles successfully and after a few seconds exits with exit code 1. The error is:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE:run
>   (default-cli) on project demo: An exception occurred while running.
>   null: InvocationTargetException: Connector configured to listen on
>   port 8080 failed to start -> [Help 1] [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] To see the full
>   stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR]
>   Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
>   please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: Pass DemoApplication.class to SpringApplication.run(). Not the controller class.

Comment: I just did it. No change.

Comment: you have spring-boot-starter-web dependency ?

Comment: And you have no log at all? You should have spring logs in your console. What happens when you run the main class from your IDE?

Comment: @alexbt, I used spring-web. Now I changed it to spring-boot-starter-web, and got another error. See the edited post.

Comment: I think that's good. Add  `server.port=8081` in your `application.properties` to use another port

Comment: thanks. This is the answer. Please write it as an answer to my post and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it stops right away indicates that Spring-Boot did not find tomcat in its classpath.

You need to include `spring-boot-starter-web` so that tomcat is found, autoconfigured and launched at startup with your application.

So basically, just add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

---

The other issue isn't a true problem:

> Connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start

It's simply caused by another process already using port 8080. To bypass this, add the following in your `application.properties`:

```
server.port=8081
```